# I don't know how to cancel job

Tags: kill, batch-jobs

I'm running some simulation by using the Linux cluster but I have some problem in my job.

I want to cancel any job(ID : 750, 752, 753 name : gib) but I don't know how to cancel this job.

Enclosed file is my job screen.[image]

How to kill a jobs by its job id?

Comment: Which job control software is the cluster using? Google for `qstat` suggests it might be Sun Grid (then Oracle Grid, now Univa Grid) or Open Grid (a fork of that).

Comment: [qstat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/qstat.html), [qdel](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/qdel.html)... lizardite - amazing ore!

Answer (score 22):

You can kill a qstat process using the qdel command:

```
qdel *ID*
```

so in your case:

```
qdel 750
```

If it won't die, you can force kill using -f option:

```
qdel -f 750
```

Comment: This is why I love this site. No question can be submitted that _someone_ won't know how to answer.

Comment: This works though I got 'option "f" not found' adding -f to force killing the job.

Answer (score 1):

To cancel the submitted job use the following command:

```
scancel jobid
```

Comment: How a slurm manager command ( `scancel` ) is related to the POSIX batch queues?